# How to remove the last part of each entry in a column based on a pattern?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I have a set of oil wells compiled in a pandas dataframe. It looks like this:

```
wells = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-01-01', '2019-01-01','2019-01-01', '2019-01-01','2019-01-01', '2019-01-01'],
                      'well': ['FIELDX-1D', 'FIELDX-2D', 'FIELDY-1C', 'FIELDY-1B', 'FIELDZ-1A', 'FIELDZ-1J'],
                      'oil_mmbd':[3.1, 5.6, 9.8, 2.5, 4.7, 6.1]})

         date       well  oil_mmbd
0  2019-01-01  FIELDX-1D       3.1
1  2019-01-01  FIELDX-2D       5.6
2  2019-01-01  FIELDY-1C       9.8
3  2019-01-01  FIELDY-1B       2.5
4  2019-01-01  FIELDZ-1A       4.7
5  2019-01-01  FIELDZ-1J       6.1
```

What I'm looking to achieve is create a new variable (ie 'Field') that compiles the aggregate output of each field. For this, I need to get rid of the last part of each well's name; but I can't seem to find the solution for this using Python and Pandas.

I want to get to a table that looks like this:

```
wells_agg = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-01-01', '2019-01-01','2019-01-01'],
                      'field': ['FIELDX', 'FIELDY', 'FIELDZ'],
                      'oil_mmbd':[8.7, 12.3, 10.8]})

         date   field  oil_mmbd
0  2019-01-01  FIELDX       8.7
1  2019-01-01  FIELDY      12.3
2  2019-01-01  FIELDZ      10.8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can strip the suffix  of the well column using   `wells.well.str.split('-').str[0])`. Therefore instead of `wells.groupby('well')`, use `wells.groupby(wells.well.str.split('-').str[0]))`. See solution below with this in mind.

```
wells.groupby(['date',wells.well.str.split('-')\
                     .str[0]]).oil_mmbd.sum().reset_index()



     date    well  oil_mmbd
0  2019-01-01  FIELDX       8.7
1  2019-01-01  FIELDY      12.3
2  2019-01-01  FIELDZ      10.8
```

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot!

Best regards.

Comment: To give others confidence to use your answer and the solution provide, you can upvote for the answer as well. You do this by clicking the up arrows on the left. I already upvoted your question.